# OneDrive Access on Company Network

Tags: firewall, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

While on my home or any open network, I am able to connect to my Microsoft OneDrive account through desktop applications like OneNote. However, while in my office and on my company's network, the connection cannot be established. Oddly though, I can access and open my OneDrive account through a browser; therefore, I know I have access to the website. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to [microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/required-urls-and-ports), OneDrive uses ports 80 and 443. The linked site reads:

> If your organization restricts computers on your network from
> connecting to the Internet, this article lists the Fully Qualified
> Domain Names (FQDNs) and ports that you should include in your
> outbound allow lists to ensure your computers can successfully use the
> consumer version of OneDrive

Your description leads me to believe that your company's firewall restricts 443, as port 80 is a common web access port assignment.

Comment: 443 is a common/the default HTTPS port. It's unlikely they'd block all 443.

Comment: @fred thanks for the input.   if access was denied via 443 wouldn't that also prevent the browser from accessing the same?  Is it possible that the endpoint OneNote is trying to access is different?

Comment: Your organization may block other aspects of the communications OneDrive requires, hence the exhaustive list in the linked reference. If those addresses are blocked, trouble ensues.